# Circle specific date in calendar Using volley response

Tags: android, android-layout, calendar

I am newbie in Calenderview android. May be this question is duplicate but I had been tried lots of question from last three days but I am unable to make a circle on specific dates and dates will come from volley response.

I really do not know how to make this because I am able get volley response but unable to set in calendar and make a circle on that.

Here is my json response.

```
{
    "status": "200",
    "msg": "Successfully",
    "response": [
        {
            "date": "2019-03-02",
            "status": "1"
        },
        {
            "date": "2019-03-04",
            "status": "1"
        },
        {
            "date": "2019-03-05",
            "status": "1"
        },
        {
            "date": "2019-03-06",
            "status": "1"
        },
        {
            "date": "2019-02-28",
            "status": "1"
        },
        {
            "date": "2019-02-27",
            "status": "1"
        },
        {
            "date": "2019-02-25",
            "status": "1"
        },
        {
            "date": "2019-02-21",
            "status": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```